# Including only Flash Player classes not AIR from library project when classes using Ant

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder, flex4.6

I have a library project that is generic (supports browser, mobile and desktop profiles) and a Flex project that runs in the browser and depends on this library. When I debug or create a release of the main application from inside Flash Builder it runs fine in the browser. But when I create the SWF from my Ant task I get multiple errors at runtime:

Error:

```
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.data::SQLConnection could not be found.
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable _class_embed_css_Assets_swf_1175738391_mx_skins_cursor_BusyCursor_347371275 is not defined.
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable _class_embed_css_Assets_swf_1175738391_cursorStretch_1614050290 is not defined.
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable ImageButtonSkin__embed_mxml_Assets_swf___brokenImage_1468354307 is not defined.
```

Here is my ANT task:

```
<!-- Build and output the Application.swf -->
<target name="Compile Flex" >

    <mxmlc file="${PROJECT_MXML_APPLICATION}" output="${PROJECT_OUTPUT_SWF}">

        <include-libraries dir="${FCLIB_BIN}" append="true">
            <include name="FcLibrary.swc" />
        </include-libraries>

    </mxmlc>
</target>
```

It seems like the AIR classes are getting compiled in to the SWF. It also seems like the defaults.css is might be getting overwritten by the FcLibrary defaults.css. I'm not sure how to solve either. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by referencing the source path rather than including the SWC.

```
<target name="Compile Flex" >

    <mxmlc file="${PROJECT_MXML_APPLICATION}" output="${PROJECT_OUTPUT_SWF}">

        <source-path path-element="${FCLIB_SRC}"/>

    </mxmlc>
</target>
```

The FCLIB_SRC would be something like "/Users/user/Documents/Workspace/FCLibrary/src".

Comment: Now I get another error: SecurityError: Error #2148: SWF file file:////Users/user/Documents/Projects/GIT/Project/bin-debug/Project.swf cannot access local resource file:////Users/user/Documents/Projects/GIT/Project/bin-debug/framework_4.5.1.21489.swf. Only local-with-filesystem and trusted local SWF files may access local resources.

Answer (score 1):

1. `include-library` is the wrong tag to use. It means exactly "put the entire library, whatever is there, regardless, of whether it is referenced in my code or not into the resulting SWF. Hence, try to change it into `<library-path dir="/where/is/your/library/">`, with child nodes `<include name="my.swc"/>`.
2. It was a bad idea in the first place to compile FcLibrary.swc for both runtimes. Just have a separate build for either one. Also check that you aren't embedding any foreign code there. By foreign I mean the Flex framework code, for example. You would want to reference that code from your final build.
3. Unless you compiled the SDK before and you know what you are doing **do not** compile against the SDK sources. That is bad both time-wise and it really complicates the compilation process. For instance, some sources rely on the presence of PBJ compiler, others assume certain directories with assets, or certain paths to contain libraries or locales or some other settings, which you will likely get wrong the first time.
4. The error in your comment is unrelated, but here's what it means: you have compiled with `static-link-runtime-shared-libraries="false"`, that is, you have instructed the compiler to generate the code, which loads RSLs from a location it thinks they are in. This is usually a good thing to do, when working on projects which use Flex framework, because it handles multiple loadings of the framework libraries and can save some caching for your application. The problem is, however, that you did not grant access to the Flash player for the directories it mentions in the error message. Loading local files in a SWF that is made to access network is restricted by default. In order to enable it, go to http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html and add your directory to the permitted list. Normally, your development environment would do that for you (you can actually do it locally, w/o accessing internet too), but the first way is just simpler.

Comment: For 2 and 3 how do I check if I'm embedding foreign code in my library and how do I know if I'm compiling against the SDK sources? On number 4 could I assume when it's on a server it will be ok? I'm deploying the swf to the same bin-debug / bin-release folder as currently exists from Flash Builder debug and should be in security sandbox already?

Comment: And thank you. I noticed someone voted to close the question. Is this not a valid question or can you tell why it is being requested closed?

Comment: Also, I just found more information on how Flex creates the MXML in the hidden .project file. I see some compiler options it's setting. Just a FYI to others and myself later to see what FB is doing for my project.

Comment: I made a second question for 4. You can post the answer there? Also, mention that I can upload to http://localhost and that will solve the problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572082/including-only-flash-player-classes-not-air-from-library-project-when-classes-us/13589571#comment18628888_13589571