# Getting an error when using my custom ANT task

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I'm getting this error when generating my own SWF with my Ant task. I've deployed it to the bin-debug and bin-release folders, both which should be in the security sandbox.

> SecurityError: Error #2148: SWF file 
>   file:////Users/user/Documents/Projects/GIT/Project/bin-debug/Project.swf
>   cannot access local resource
>   file:////Users/user/Documents/Projects/GIT/Project/bin-debug/framework_4.5.1.214‌​89.swf.
>   Only local-with-filesystem and trusted local SWF files may access
>   local resources.

If I run build or debug from Flash Builder the project loads correctly without error.

Here is my build script:

```
<mxmlc file="${PROJECT_MXML_APPLICATION}" output="${PROJECT_OUTPUT_SWF}">

    <source-path path-element="${FCLIB_SRC}"/>

</mxmlc>
```

I've also tried adding use-network="true" in the mxmlc call with no change.

Answer (score 1):

I had to upload it to a server, "http://localhost/" or "http://mydomain.com" to make it work. I had added the folders to the trusted sandbox (by right clicking and choosing global settings > preferences > trusted domains > add). This didn't solve it (maybe it's a problem with the new Flash Player Preferences program (Mac OSX). I could have checked for the FlashBuilder.cfg (forgot the location) of trusted locations.

A more indepth answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13589571/441016).